# How to make audit trail log entries for each new row of data when multiple input at once?

Tags: excel, vba, audit, audit-trail

I am new to VBA and have adapted various pieces of code from forums.

The audit trail works great, I wanted it to bring through a unique identifier and column header as well as cell changed due to the main data table being constantly sorted by users. I only wanted changes made to the worksheet entitled 'Main' recorded - I have probably done this in a long-winded manner, but it works well.

My query is a request on how I can adapt it further. On the 'Main' data sheet a user may bring through multiple new records at a time (not a significant amount, anywhere from 1-15 rows of data). The audit trail will bring through the value in column A only for the first record. Is it possible to have it that it would bring through just the value of column A for each of the records when pasted in at the same time? 
I am looking to analyse the time difference between the Sales Order being saved as complete and then brought through to my delivery planner spreadsheet.

```
Option Explicit
Public PriorVal As String

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim NR As Long
    With Sheets("AuditLog")
        NR = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Range("A" & NR).Value = Environ("UserName")
        .Range("B" & NR).Value = Environ("ComputerName")
        .Range("C" & NR).Value = Now
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If IsError(Selection(1).Value) = True Then
     PriorVal = "Error"
    ElseIf Selection(1).Value = "" Then
        PriorVal = "Blank"
    Else
        PriorVal = Selection(1).Value
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
Dim NR As Long
If sh.Name = "AuditLog" Then Exit Sub     'allows you to edit the log sheet
If sh.Name = "Order data" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "Tables" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "PO prep sheet" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "PO upload sheet" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "Purchase Orders" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "Despatches" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "Comments" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "Late Codes" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "Haulage costs" Then Exit Sub
If sh.Name = "Haulier instruction" Then Exit Sub

If Target.Address = "$R$3" Then Exit Sub

Application.EnableEvents = False
    With Sheets("AuditLog")
        NR = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Range("A" & NR).Value = Environ("UserName")
        .Range("B" & NR).Value = Environ("ComputerName")
        .Range("C" & NR).Value = Now
        .Range("D" & NR).Value = sh.Name
        .Range("E" & NR).Value = Target.Address
        .Range("F" & NR).Value = Cells(5, Target.Column)
        .Range("G" & NR).Value = PriorVal
        .Range("H" & NR).Value = Target(1).Value
        .Range("I" & NR).Value = Cells(Target.Row, 1)
        NR = NR + 1
    End With
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you only want changes to `Worksheets("Main")`, then simplify (and improve the accuracy of) your `Workbook_SheetChange()` method. Eliminate all the `If sh.Name = "x" Then Exit Sub`. Replace it with one simple `If sh.Name <> "Main" Then Exit Sub`. Much easier. Much less code. Not broken if someone adds a new `worksheets("Watch Me Break Rapture's Code")`. :D

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure how it's triggered on a paste, but I would think that you want the `Worksheet_Change` event. You only get `Target as Range` as the parameter, but you can use `if Target.Parent.Name <> "Main"` to determine if you're on the right worksheet. I _think_ that `Target` will be the entire range that's pasted in, but I'm not 100% certain of that.

Comment: @FreeMan Thank you very much for your suggestions!  I have implemented and tested your first comment and it is much more efficient use of code :)   I will look into the 2nd suggestion - Ideally it would just be the values in column A for all rows, as opposed to all pasted which would be A:O

Comment: In your `Workbook_Open` method, capture the values from column A of your `"Main"` worksheet (maybe in an array.. much faster). Then in your `Change` method, capture the values in column A again (in a different array). Compare the 2 arrays. This will give you the new records. Don't forget to update your first array with new values so that you can make the comparison next time record(s) are added

Comment: @FreeMan - When you use the `Worksheet_Change` event, the `Target.Parent.Name <> "Main"`-test is not necessary. The subroutine sits in the Main Module.

Comment: Excellent point, @MarcoVos. I don't do a lot of event handling so some of the finer points escape me.

Comment: @Zac thank you for your suggestion.  I am completely new to VBA.  With using your suggested method, would the arrays capture and output the data from column A in the AuditLog and comparisons from both sets done there?  Ideally all I want output in the AuditLog once new lines of data are pasted in is the Sales Order Number (Column A) for each row with the time.  The AuditLog table is then going to be used to analyse the Sales Order Input data which will be taken from SQL server to measure the time difference between order 1234 being input to Sage and order 1234 being input to this excel sheet

Comment: If you just want to get values from a column, there are different ways you can approach this. But if we go with my suggested approach, when you compare the 2 arrays, you will know what the new rows are. Depending on how you capture this array, you could just capture the value from your array and copy it where you want. For time stamp, you can use **`TimeValue(Now)`**. Although I would recommend to use **`Now()`** which gives you both date and time